# Filter in Get Request from DOL data

Tags: labor

I am trying to filter my search on the DOL API to capture only observations meeting a particular criteria. In addition, I will need to skip some observations.

This is the code I am using below. Number 1 works, but when I try to introduce a filter, as in number 2, I get an error. Ultimately, I would like to include both a filter and skip.

1)

```
msha_api <- GET("http://api.dol.gov/V1/Mining/FullMineInfo/MSHA_mines/?Key=xxx&$skip=100", accept("application/json"))
```

2)

```
msha_api <- GET("http://api.dol.gov/V1/Mining/FullMineInfo/MSHA_mines/?Key=xxx&$filter=PRIMARY_CANVASS eq 'Coal'", accept("application/json"))
```

Any advice/help on how to go about including both a `filer` and a `skip` in the DOL API call?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a URL encoding issue with R... try this: (note the `+` instead of  [space])

```
msha_api <- GET("http://api.dol.gov/V1/Mining/FullMineInfo/MSHA_mines/?Key=xxxx&$filter=PRIMARY_CANVASS+eq+'Coal'", accept("application/json"))
```

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/URLencode.html for how to do this programmatically

Screenshot of results below:

[image: working results]